# Angular 15 host application not able to render nested component from angular 13 MFE application

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack-module-federation, angular15

I'm facing challenging to render Angular 13 MFE's in angular 15 host application.

Here is my application structure

I have created MFE's with angular 13 version and trying to use those in Angular 15 host application.

**Issue:**

- I have Angular 15 version host application and loading MFE from angular 13 version able to load page from MFE but HTML is not rendering.
- In the page i have some element it is rendering fine but not rendering nested component.

**MFE webpack.config.js**

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;
const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(path.join(__dirname, "tsconfig.json"), [
  /* mapped paths to share */
]);
module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "about",
    publicPath: "auto",
    scriptType: "text/javascript",
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    },
  },
  // experiments: {
  //   outputModule: true
  // },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      // library: { type: "module" },
      library: { type: "var", name: "about" },
      // For remotes (please adjust)
      name: "about",
      filename: "about.js",
      exposes: {
        "./about": "./src/loadApp.ts",
        "./aboutModule": "./src/app/about/about.module.ts",
      },
      shared: share({
        "@angular/core": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: ">=12.0.0 <=16.1.6",
          eager: true,
        },
        "@angular/common": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: ">=12.0.0 <=16.1.6",
          eager: true,
        },
        "@angular/common/http": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: ">=12.0.0 <=16.1.6",
        },
        "@angular/router": {
          singleton: false,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: ">=12.0.0 <=16.1.6",
          eager: true,
        },
        "@angular/forms": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: ">=12.0.0 <=16.1.6",
        },
        "@angular/animations": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: "auto",
          eager: true,
        },
        "ngx-toastr": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: ">=12.0.0 <=17.0.2",
        },
        "ngx-spinner": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: ">=9.0.2 <=16.0.2",
        },
        "ngx-bootstrap": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: "auto",
        },
        ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors(),
      }),
    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

Below image i can able to load about MFE in the host application and h2 tag but not loading  component HTML.

inside  component have some static text.

MFE developed in **13.3.9** angular version.

Host application **15.2.9** angular version,

**MFE About component**

```
<h2>Hello....</h2>
<app-text></app-text>
```

**text component**

```
<h2> Title </h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
```

[image]

Comment: if you run the Angular 13 app on its own, does the nested component load correctly?

Comment: Please share your module federation config from `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: Hi @BizzyBob, I have updated MFE webpack.config.js file

Comment: Hi @BizzyBob, I have updated some more information in question details it will help!.
Thank!

Comment: if you run the Angular 13 app on its own, does the nested component load correctly? 
Ans: yes, It is working fine